# Can all be used with a singular noun

Tags: grammaticality, determiners, predeterminers

[This website](http://www.grammar.cl/english/all-every-each.htm) talks about how all should only be used with plural nouns.  But I'm wanting to say "all the following," and "all the followings" doesn't work.  And every and each doesn't work either.  I am a native speaker, and I fell like "all the following" is perfectly fine.  So, can all be used with a singular noun?  And if yes, then why doesn't this violate the grammar (the grammar being " how all should only be used with plural nouns" on the website)?

---

I realize that "all of the following" works. However I'd prefer to use "all the following." Although if it doesn't work, I'm willing to use "all of" instead of "all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look a little further down in that article, and you will see the construction ***All + of + determiner + noun***. The article notes that in this construction,

> The noun can be singular, plural or an uncountable noun. These nouns can also be replaced by pronouns.
>   *You need to read **all of the book**.*
>   ***All of the pages*** are yellow and old.

Most important for you, the article also notes that

> We can also remove ***OF*** before the determiner + noun (but we must use ***OF*** before a pronoun)
>   *You need to read **all the book**.*
>   ***All the pages*** are yellow and old.

Your use has a determiner and could be rewritten as *all **of** the following*, so it's fine to use a singular noun.

Comment: I realize that "all of the following" works.  However I'd prefer to use "all the following," and it doesn't say its ok to use only "all" with singular nouns.  Although if it doesn't work, I'm willing to use "all of" instead of "all".

Comment: It *does* say it's ok—that's what "We can...remove ***OF*** before the determiner" means: you can change *all of the following* to  *all the following*. What native speakers generally *don't* say is something like *all apple is delicious*. It can, though, be either *all of the apple is delicious* or *all the apple is delicious*.